# CosmosDB Mongo API: select specific fields

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm using Azure CosmosDB Data explorer (Azure Portal -> Azure Cosmos DB -> Data Explorer). There're only JSON query string `{"foo": "bar"}`. How can I select only specific field or use `aggregate` command there?
e.g., document structure:

```
{
  "age": 30,
  "city": "Oslo"
}
```

and I would to select only:

```
{
  "city": "Oslo"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I select only specific field or use aggregate command there?

To select only specific field, please refer to below command in mongo shell on portal:

> get all data from city field with _id

```
db.coll.find({}, {city:1})
```

> get all data from city field without _id

```
db.coll.find({}, {city:1,_id:0})
```

Test:

[image]

As for the aggregation function,cosmos db mongo api only supports partial of the all mongo aggregation functions,please refer to this [document](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#aggregation-pipelinea) to check the supported features.